# Why is Miniconda not running the latest version of Spyder?

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, spyder, miniconda

I am in my tensorflow env on my minicoda prompt and I have just installed the latest version of Spyder via the following prompt: `conda update spyder`. Before I updated spyder I was on v4.1.3. I then searched to see if it was installed correctly with the following prompt: `conda search -f spyder` which brought up this list:

[image]

However, when I run spyder from miniconda: `spyder` (or even startup the application by clicking on the icon) it still launches my previous version of 4.1.3

[image]

What I then tried to do was run the prompt `spyder=5.05` but it still launches version 4.1.3.

In my miniconda3\Lib\site-packages directory my spyder folder's file __init__.py has version = 4.1.3 so I understand that that is why it is launching 4.1.3. I do not know why this spyder folder was not updated. You can also see the pkgs folder there is only Spyder v4.1.3

[image]

Can someone please help me get the latest version of spyder to run without me having to uninstall and reinstall it, as I have all my preferences set on spyder and apparently there is no way of exporting and then importing them. Thanks

Comment: `conda` tries to resolve version conflicts between packages. Maybe it cannot update spyder because of incompatibilities with other packages. Try to explicitly install the newest version with `conda install spyder=5.0.5`. It should tell you what package changes are required to install that version, or why it's not possible...

Comment: `conda search` searches through the packages that you **could** install. i.e. those that match your query from the currently configured channels. To see which packages you have actually installed, you need to run `conda info`

Answer (score 1):

In my environment on my Miniconda prompt I typed in `conda install spyder=5.0.5` and this resolved the issue. I now have Spyder 5.0.5! Acknowledgements to MB-F for giving the solution in the comment section.

Comment: Please accept you own answer if it solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it in this order:

`conda update anaconda`

and then

`conda install spyder=5`

this will allow you to successfully upgrade to version 5.

If it didn't help, then do this:

`conda install conda-forge::spyder[version='>=5.0.0]`

You can put another version

Comment: OP is running `miniconda`, so there is no indication to run `conda update anaconda`